# What is meaning of work done without doing net work on object gets stored as potential energy? There are similar questions but some doubts are still

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

In a conservative system ***positive Work done by external force or negative work done by conservative force without accelerating or giving Kinetic energy to the object, gets stored as potential energy of the object.***

Are the following understandings correct?

**1- if F(ext)↑ = mg↓ then F(ext)-mg=0 then u=v=0, so to move the object, at the beginning take F(ext)=mg+∆f. ∆f should be very small compared to mg, ***lets say if mg=10N then ∆f≈0.001N***. ∆f causes upward acceleration such that ***lets say ∆v=0.01ms-¹*** and after that ∆f is removed and only F(ext) balances the mg and object continues with v=0.01ms-1.**  Is this point has any error? Can we have have larger ∆f like 1000N?

**2- Is it correct that ∆v should be ≈0 i.e. v=0.01ms-1 so that object may not gain Kinetic energy?** Some say that acceleration should be zero or velocity should be constant. But I know that for higher velocities there will be higher K.E. as well. Can we have larger velocity?

**3-if F(ext) is just balancing the mg then net force =0 then none forces seem to be able of doing work as if F(ext) exerts upward then mg is exerting equal amount of force downwards ***the situation is similar to object moving with constant velocity due its inertia***. Then why is work associated to either F(ext) as W=mgh or F(gravity) as W=-mgh?**

Comment: 1- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522649/

2- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/690037/

3- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/464981/

4- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/462383/f

5- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103024/

Comment: I have reverted a major edit which invalidated at least one existing answer. To access previous versions of a question, click the “edited X ago” text next to the user card at the bottom. To ask a related follow-up question, just ask a new question. For closely-related questions, it is polite to include links in each question, with some text clarifying for the casual reader how the questions are related but distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\Delta \vec F$ is unnecessary. Simply start with some initial $\vec v\ne 0$. There is no requirement that $\vec v$ should be small and certainly no requirement that it be 0 initially. Since the net force is 0, there is no acceleration and the object simply continues moving at a constant $\vec v$.
2. If you get rid of the unnecessary $\Delta \vec F$ then automatically there is no $\Delta \vec v$.
3. I think in terms of power. The external force is upwards and $v$ is upwards, so $P_{ext}=\vec F_{ext} \cdot \vec v$ is positive while $P_g=\vec F_g \cdot \vec v$ is negative. Mechanical power enters the object from the external force and leaves the object from the gravitational force. The net is zero, but the individual forces still transfer power.

Comment: I have removed some comments about the revision history for this question.

Comment: @Dale You said that if object is at rest then apply large impulsive force and immediately after set start time. What about the work done by the impulsive force? Why that seems to be excluded?

Comment: Let's say **mass of object=1kg, ext force= 1010N, Fg= -10N, displacement=0.002m**. solving this **I get v=2ms-1 and net work done= 2J.** From your one of the comments *I infer that 2J of work is ignored.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you are either misreading what you have seen, or you have been consulting unreliable (i.e. *incorrect*) sources. Applying a force $F=mg$ will not, by itself, cause potential energy to increase. (And, of course, $mg$ is not the only force that can increase P.E.)  Another condition is needed: in addition to $F=mg$, the object must also be being displaced upward.

As you point out, applying a force $mg$ does not cause a change in velocity, and one can conclude that no work is being done.  However, the correct statement is "No *net* work is being done."   Both the force of gravity *and* your hand are doing work, but if the external applied force is $F_\mathrm{ext} =mg$, the work done by gravity is equal in magnitude but opposite in sign to the work done by your hand.

When making a statement about work done, *you must always identify which force is being considered, or whether or not you are referring to *net* force*.

**Addition after comments**

Is zero net force the same as no force at all?  Yes, from the point of view of dynamics.

The concept of internal and external forces is useful for the definition of potential energy.  The concept of potential energy is not necessary for calculating the dynamics of a system, but it can certainly simplify things. In order to tell which forces are internal and which are external one first has to decide what comprises the system.  For example, in the case you present you can consider the system to be the box, or the Earth-box system.  In the former case, both gravity and your hand provide external forces.  In the latter case, gravity is internal and the force provided by your hand is external.

The definition of potential energy:
$$PE = -W_\mathrm{internal,\; conservative}$$
Potential energy is the negative of work done by internal conservative forces.   If the system is the book alone, there is only one object and there are no internal forces.  Potential energy is *not defined*.  For the case of the Earth-box system, the potential energy is the integral of the force of gravity time the displacement.  Near the surface of the earth the force of gravity is nearly constant, and it points *down*.  If you use an external force to lift the box (your hand) the displacement is *up*. With all that he potential energy, negative of the work done by gravity, becomes after lifting the box
$$PE = -F_\mathrm{gravity} h = - (-mg)(+d) = mgh$$
This is the potential energy of the Earth-box system, not of the box. The PE of the box alone is *not defined*. Unfortunately, most textbooks correctly define potential energy (if they give the definition at all) *after* introducing scenarios of objects moving near the surface of the Earth, and $PE = mgh$ is presented without justification.  The definition is presented *later*.  This order of presentation sometimes creates confusion.

I don't quite understand what's confusing you.  I hope this long-winded discussion somehow hits the target and clears things up for you.

Comment: What about inertia? Once object starts moving upwards and f(ext)=mg then clearly forces cancel out so net force=0 therefore object is moving on its own similar to planets revolving in orbits or like objects thrown in outer space.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  What is the confusion about that?

Comment: My confusion is that if object is moving on its own then why work is labelled as done by external force or internal force?

Comment: I feel that two equal and opposite forces = no force. (Except the case of pressure). Situation seems similar to throwing object from international space station into space.

Comment: If I throw object in space, work done by me= F. Displacement of hand. But after then the object carries on with same velocity in absence of net opposing force.

Comment: I am considering two equal and opposite forces as absence of any force.